# Luggage damage - It's been 3 months and I haven't heard anything!

Tags: lhr, damaged-luggage, air-china

My suitcase and most of it's contents were broken and battered in a recent flight, I filed this with the airline (Air China for those wondering..) but have yet to receive any official response. I've called them what must be close to 100 times by now, and every time I've been told either "can you please email this address instead, we'll get back to you right away" or "we've told the airport and are waiting for their response".

The airport in question is Heathrow (Terminal 2, if that makes a difference), I can't imagine it takes them more than 3 months to do **something** about damaged luggage..

Does anyone know what else I can do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is effectively a rant. Please edit the question so that it becomes answerable on this site.

Comment: Have you provided them with itemized lists of what was damaged?  Receipts to verify those items' value?  Have you filed a report with your travel insurance provider (along with the items mentioned above)?

Comment: Do you have travel insurnace you could claim on instead (and leave it to them to chase Air China)?

Comment: @Tom I provided them with a list of items as well as pictures to show damages, I didn't file with my travel insurance though! I never even thought to go through my travel insurance, I'll dig out the details.